# slide jquery from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that I would like to slide from the left on button click. Ultimately I would like to have the div have a negative so its off the screen until toggled. If the button is clicked again it should close. I have tried animate and cannot seem to get it to work correctly. Here is my code.

this is the css

```
 .feature_content {
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: none;
```

This is the javascript

```
     $("button").click(function(){
    $(".feature_content").toggle({left: -423});
```

this is the html

```
<div class="feature_content">
   this is the div to toggle
</div>


<button>This is the button</button>
```

Comment: isn't it already working? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vf0ssvz/). what is the problem?

Comment: **slide from the left on button click**   
Updated fiddle : 

`http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/7vf0ssvz/1/`

Comment: Well what I would like it do to is instead of the text building to full width and appearing jumbled as its building I would like for it to just slide in view already built. Example is the same as mine where it goes from with of 0 to 100% which causes the text to appear like it does.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){ $("button").click(function(){ $(".feature_content").toggle({left: -423});
});
});

Comment: Well what I would like it do to is instead of the text building to full width and appearing jumbled as its building I would like for it to just slide in view already built. Your example is the same as mine where it goes from with of 0 to 100% which causes the text to appear like it does.